# LOOKUPVALUE after FILTER?

Tags: lookup, powerbi, dax

Is there a way in PowerBI to concatenate/merge two columns with integer values?

For example,

```
 Employee    Wage      Concatenate (what I need)        Concatenate without Seperator
 1234        001          1234-001                      1234001
 1234        002          1234-002                      1234002
 456789      009          456789-009                    456789009
 34005       null         34005-                        34005 
 34          005          34-005                        34005
```

The third column can either be a string or an integer, but I would like to have some kind of separator (because if I have a null value as seen in row 4 above, the value in the Concatenate column is essentially useless and I don't want it included in my lookup. I will be using the Concatenation to lookup values in another table. So if I pull the value associated with an Employee that has no wage, I don't want the value of that row to be the same as the row with Employee 34 and Wage 005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this in the Edit Query window in Power Query by adding a custom column. Assuming Employee is numeric but Wage is a text field (because of the leading zeroes) and assuming Employee can never be null, but wage can be:

```
=Text.From([Employee]) & "-" & (if [Wage] is null then "" else [Wage])
```

You can also do this in DAX as a calculated column with nested concatenates:

```
=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE([Employee], "-"), [Wage])
```